# What's the best way to keep user logged in with cookie and JWT?

Tags: reactjs, jwt

I'm making an SPA with Laravel REST API and trying to keep it stateless. Right now I'm trying to achieve proper JWT authentication and 'remember me' functionality.

1. On successful login the client receives a bearer token in the payload (stored in Redux state) which will be used for further requests as authorization.
2. On login I also generate an `httpOnly` cookie with an access token and send it back.
3. On page reload I make a request (`credentials: "include"`) and if the access token has not expired the client gets a new bearer token.

My questions:

1. Is it a good approach?
2. Is it safe to store bearer token in Redux state?

Comment: Where is the Redux state you mention? On the client side or the server side?

Comment: Client side in-memory

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is fine. Two important caveats:

1. Do not save the access token in local storage.
2. Set the httpOnly flag for the refresh token.